# Choose Certificate with Smart Card Authentication IIS7 Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, smartcard

I am trying to set up smart card authentication for a website that I have created.  Setting authentication to Windows and setting SSL to required I can get the smart card reader to pop up when they go to the web site.  There are 2 credentials on the card though and only one of them is showing up as an option (the information I need is on the other credential).  I asked a co worker and he said in IIS 6 there was a way to specify a location on the smart card to look for certificates.  I have been researching this issue for about a week now but haven't been able to find a solution to this issue yet.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS really only knows about certificate-based authentication, not smart-cards per se (which is really just a form of cert-based authentication). Configure your site to use certificate-based authentication, eg "Require Client Certificates" and IIS will chain the call down to Windows security, which, in turn, recognizes that among the sources for identity certificates is the smartcard reader. Depending upon your site requirements, you may also need to enable Certificate Mapping, which translates certificates into Windows account identities.

Comment: David, this topic seems to be about IIS7 not 6. And also he successfully reaches the certificate on card. But only one of two as i understood.

Comment: I've removed the "6" from the IIS designation. The OP stated that he had been told "IIS6" allowed for a designation of the source on a smart card for reading a certificate, and my reply was to point out that neither IIS6 nor IIS7 specifically knows about smart cards; they know about certificate-based authentication. A smart card is simply a vehicle carrying the certs.

Comment: Looking directly at the card on my computer and there are 3 certs on it.  I have set up mapping trying that avenue,  I was able to see the cards before but the certificate that I needed wasn't listed.  Somewhere through this process a change i made made it so it doesn't show the smart card anymore.  I am trying to get it showing again to see what options are available now.  I will let you know when I get it showing again.

Comment: with ssl set to accept and authentication set to windows I get user name and password along with the smart cards on the server.  the client only shows the user name and password.  changing this to required doesn't prompt anything on either location (head hits desk).

Comment: when I set it to require I am not prompted for anything.  We are thinking we may have a bad server at this point.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to have been of some help. Good luck.

Comment: installed the new server and everything is working correctly now.  Thank you so much for the information on mapping.

Answer (score 1):

When certificates are required (or accepted) IIS will ask for a client cert in the SSL negotiation when the session is started.  IIS will send a list of the Certificate Authorities it trusts to the client.  The client then takes those and sees which match the list of Certificate Authorities it trusts.  It then take sthe list of common entries and checks to see if it has any certs issued by a CA both sides trust.  Generally, if there are none it will simply not send a cert and the request fails if the cert is required.  If there is just one certificate IE will generally send that without asking the client which cert to send, but it will prompt for a PIN if required.  Finally, if there are more than one certificate issued by a CA both sides trust then a dialog box will be presented to the client asking which cert to use.

In this case it sounds like perhaps the credential (certificate) you want the client to send is issued by a Certificate Authority that isn't trusted by one or both sides.